# google sheets webscraping , importxml fails

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I have this url `https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/TAGLTEC:MK`

I want to **scrape** the 0.8225 element into my google sheets.
`E58 is cell with url https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/TAGLTEC:MK`

the **scraping** query i used was `=REPLACE(E58,(E58,"//span[@class='priceText__06f600fa3e']"),1, 3, "")` but it fails

[image]

Comment: Possibly hit an anti-bot measure? Did you check the `//body`? I think that would be the longer term issue. Were that not the problem, for you, then the dynamic class values would be, and so you would need to alter the xpath to partial match on the static part of the class attribute for that `span` tag (`priceText`)

Comment: This site is testing how you fetch data by `userAgent: navigator.userAgent` and unfortunately it doesn't give any information here, although you can see in the source if page. Everything after `<div id="root" ____` is not abailable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
=importxml("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/TAGLTEC:MK","//section[@class='box main']")
```

and

```
=index(flatten(importxml("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/TAGLTEC:MK","//section[@class='info']")),2,1)
```

and you will see the exact reason why there is no way to retrieve data by using importxml.